# SSD - Trim - trimmed a lot of data

Tags: xubuntu, ssd, fstab, debian, trim

I have a Xubuntu distribution and a new SSD (Plextor 128GB)

Partitions scheme:

```
16GB / 
52GB home
rest free
```

Every day Cron runs script:

```
#!/bin/sh
LOG=/var/log/trim.log
echo "*** $(date -R) ***" >> $LOG
fstrim -v / >> $LOG
fstrim -v /home >> $LOG
```

But I see in logs, that fstrim trimmed large amount of data (even when I only use Facebook these days).

```
*** Tue, 22 Sep 2015 16:25:49 +0200 ***
/: 16 GiB (17197719552 bytes) trimmed
/home: 56,1 GiB (60247904256 bytes) trimmed
*** Wed, 23 Sep 2015 17:09:07 +0200 ***
/: 16 GiB (17198047232 bytes) trimmed
/home: 56,1 GiB (60259184640 bytes) trimmed
*** Thu, 24 Sep 2015 18:17:21 +0200 ***
/: 16 GiB (17197322240 bytes) trimmed
/home: 56,1 GiB (60245733376 bytes) trimmed
*** Sun, 27 Sep 2015 20:47:52 +0200 ***
/: 16,1 GiB (17317892096 bytes) trimmed
/home: 55,3 GiB (59397570560 bytes) trimmed
*** Mon, 28 Sep 2015 16:42:22 +0200 ***
/: 16,1 GiB (17317916672 bytes) trimmed
/home: 55,3 GiB (59334848512 bytes) trimmed
*** Tue, 29 Sep 2015 16:42:44 +0200 ***
/: 16,1 GiB (17317687296 bytes) trimmed
/home: 55,3 GiB (59325485056 bytes) trimmed
*** Wed, 30 Sep 2015 18:29:24 +0200 ***
/: 16,2 GiB (17407598592 bytes) trimmed
/home: 55,2 GiB (59313143808 bytes) trimmed
*** Thu, 01 Oct 2015 16:52:46 +0200 ***
/: 16,1 GiB (17315864576 bytes) trimmed
/home: 55,2 GiB (59314216960 bytes) trimmed
*** Sun, 04 Oct 2015 22:12:47 +0200 ***
/: 16,1 GiB (17315987456 bytes) trimmed
/home: 55,6 GiB (59722145792 bytes) trimmed
*** Mon, 05 Oct 2015 12:44:36 +0200 ***
/: 16,1 GiB (17316077568 bytes) trimmed
/home: 55,5 GiB (59557986304 bytes) trimmed
```

Could You explain me, why is that?
I'm afraid, that SSD lifetime will be short.
Thanks in advance.